# Expression must have a constant value (Error in C)

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, constants

This is my code:

```
int main (void) {

    struct state
    {
        int output;
        int time;
        const struct state *next[4];
    };

    typedef const struct state state_t;

    # define wait1noclick &fsm[0]
    # define fast2 &fsm[1]
    # define wait2noclick &fsm[2]
    # define fast1 &fsm[3]
    # define wait1click &fsm[4]
    # define wait1 &fsm[5]
    # define wait2click &fsm[6]
    # define wait2 &fsm[7]

    state_t fsm[8] = 
    {
        {0xC, 600, {wait1noclick, fast2, wait1click, fast2}},
        {0x1, 150, {fast2, wait2noclick, fast2, wait2noclick}},
        {0x3, 600, {wait2noclick, fast1, wait2click, fast1}},
        {0x4, 150, {fast1, wait1noclick, fast1, wait1noclick}},
        {0x8, 200, {wait1click, wait1, wait1click, wait1}},
        {0x5, 200, {wait1, fast2, wait1, fast2}},
        {0x2, 200, {wait2click, wait2, wait2click, wait2}},
        {0xA, 200, {wait2, fast1, wait2, fast1}}
    };
}
```

It is suposed to compile without problems but I am getting this error message all the time, 4 times in each "fsm" row:

```
error: #28: expression must have a constant value
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should do it outside of `main`, as the addresses have to be constant, I.e. have a static storage class. And defining types inside of `main` is a bad idea by itself.

Comment: works fine outside the `main` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves the problem. If you want, post it like an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: works fine as-is with gcc, though. The answer below explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code from the point of view of modern C language.

But if you are using a very pedantic old C89/90 compiler, it will insist on all aggregate initializers to be made up from *constant expressions*. This will prevent you from using addresses of local objects in such initializers, since such addresses are not constants.

This restriction has been lifted in C99: aggregate initializers for automatic objects are no longer restricted to constant expressions only.

However, every C89/90 compiler I know has been ignoring that restriction and supporting the modern behavior since the beginning of times. Could it be that your compiler is deliberately configured for very pedantic enforcement of C89/90 rules?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I find your explanation a bit hard to understand, in part because English is not my principal language and maybe I don't have the knowledge necessary. But I understand that the problem is that my compiler is an old one and requires constants to be initialized outside the main. If you are interested, I am using Keil uVision4. Thank you again for the explanation!

Comment: @Sergio: Your compiler is not necessarily "old". It might simply be configured to pedantically enforce the rules of "classic" C language standard from 1989. Whether it is its "natural" configuration - I don't really know.